# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present

Tags: javascript

Latest version of Google Chrome & Opera are throwing this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertRule' on 'CSSStyleSheet': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

Any ideas where this new bug is coming from and how to fix?

Comment: It is impossible to answer... You need to give a link that shows the problem or code that recreates it. This is like saying my car makes this sound, but you do not let the mechanic see or hear it.

Comment: Throwing that error... on your website that you code? On all websites? Are you asking about a problem with your own CSS, or a possible browser bug? Cannot answer in current form.

Comment: I'm getting this to on a site that has been working for months and still works with no issues in IE (was working as recent as a few days ago in Chrome).  Was there a recent update to Chrome?

Comment: For further clarification, it looks as though the error is occurring in the NETEYE Activity Indicator plugin.

Comment: We just had this happen to our site roughly 10hrs ago - there seems to be some api library change somewhere. I know that's vague, but I just woke up & am trying to investigate. Only occurring in Chrome

Comment: See "answer" below - Chromium update caused a plugin that didn't strictly adhere to the specs to break

Answer (score 12):

More information: still understanding what this is, but someone pushed out bad code and hosed us all somehow:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&groupby=&sort=&id=319695

---

EDIT: this issue seems to have come from a recent Chromium update, which is breaking Neteye. Disabling Neteye for the moment seems to be the solution, while they iron out what to do or update Neteye

EDIT: this may supply a fix - seems like the PR never made it in
https://github.com/bizzynut/jquery-plugins/commit/f000dc6347fbcabf4e3fd47732ddd97c73067755

SOLUTION: above fix works for solving NetEye issue

activity-indicator.js
line 150:
- document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule);
+ document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(rule, 0);

Comment: Good job for finding this. Seems like Chrome want to push against specification which requires both parameters to stylesheet.insertRule be passed. If you're looking for a quick fix, just do stylesheet.insertRule(myCurrentWorkingRule, 0);

Comment: I have found that you will still get this error -- even when including the second insertRule parameter -- if the stylesheet has a `@charset` or `@import` at the very beginning.  My solution is to use `document.stylesheets[0].insertRule(rule, document.stylesheets[0].rules.length);` instead. See https://github.com/lvivski/anima/issues/27 for more info.