# Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I get weird issue after trying to display xml data through xsl on html. when I compile the html file on my desktop, no issue shows up. However, when I upload these files to my server and compile the html file, I get this error message on Opera latest version: "**Uncaught NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element is null**"

I also get similar issue when run that on FF says "**NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE: Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIXSLTProcessor.importStylesheet]**".

it is exact same code from w3school I'm using, but surprisingly this issue on my side happening...

you can find the code [The full code XSLT - On the Client](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp)

The xml file::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
.
.
</catalog>
```

The xsl file::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The html file::

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(filename)
{
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
  }
else
  {
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xml");
xsl = loadXMLDoc("cdcatalog.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document")
  {
  ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = ex;
  }
// code for Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayResult()">
<div id="example" />
</body>
</html>
```

any idea why such none sense errors are showing up on these browsers... The issue is also on other browsers and this is just an example where I keep testing..

Comment: `document.getElementById("example")`: is there any element with an *id* of `example` in the source document?

Comment: I tried http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=cdcatalog with both current Firefox and Opera on Windows 8.1 and get no errors in the error console and the cd collection is displayed fine. So the problem is not reproducible, you will need to post a URL for us to allow us to reproduce the problem or you will need to check yourself what is different in your setup. For instance, with what MIME type does your server serve the `cdcatalog.xsl` document, are you sure the XMLHttpRequests for it are populating `responseXML` correctly?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest for instance which says "If the server doesn't apply the text/xml Content-Type header, you can use overrideMimeType()to force XMLHttpRequest to parse it as XML anyway.". So that could be one reason why Firefox does not have an executable stylesheet.

Comment: you are right@MartinHonnen. Thanks. I had to check my web server settings to be sure whether it supports the xsl xml mime types, and found out that they are supported, but only xsl is not activated. now things are great and everything works fine. Thanks again.

Comment: @Digitalsite, I will summarize my suggestions in an answer so that you can accept it and this question is properly treated as being answered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010347/uncaught-typeerror-failed-to-execute-insertrule-on-cssstylesheet-2-argumen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryit.asp?filename=cdcatalog works fine for me with Firefox and Opera so there must be some difference in your settings. For instance if the `catalog.xsl` file is not served with a proper XML MIME type the XMLHttpRequest might not populate the `responseXML` property with the stylesheet code which could explain why Firefox complains on the `importStylesheet` call.